# Raphaël JS. Rubberband path between two shapes

Tags: canvas, svg, raphael

Anyone has sample code for drawing a rubber band style path between two shapes in Raphael.

I saw few questions around drawing path progressively at [How to draw a vector path progressively? (Raphael.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js)

But my requirement is to be able to click on one shape and move the mouse to the other shape and while the mouse moves, there should be a line path following the mouse like a rubber band. Once the click happens on the second shape the line path has to be locked in.

I tried the Joint.js http://www.jointjs.com/ with Raphael but it can draw lines but not interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the basic code to get you started:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerWidth;
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, w, h);
var nodes = paper.set();

var circle1 = paper.circle(w/8, h/3, w/16)
    .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .click(line);
var circle2 = paper.circle(w - w/8, h/3, w/16).attr({fill: "#000"})
    .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .click(line);


function line() {
  var band = paper.path("M 0 0").attr({"stroke-width": 5})
  band.node.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  dimensions = this.getBBox();
  var x = dimensions.x + dimensions.width/2;
  var y = dimensions.y + dimensions.height/2;
  if (!window.onmousemove) {
    window.onmousemove = function(e){
        band.attr({path: "M " + x + " " + y + "L " + e.x + " " + e.y});
    }
  }
  else {
     window.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

You can check out a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/57myn/