# how to animate a curve in raphael js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have drawn a coil like structure

```
var pathCommand = "M 10 50 l 10 0 ";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 pathCommand += "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20 " + "c -10   0   0  20  15  20 ";
}
var pc = paper.path(pathCommand);`enter code here`
            pc.attr({
                stroke: '#000',
                'stroke-width': 3
            });
```

but I want to show this with animation as if it is being drawn pixel by pixel.
I have tried this

```
var pc = paper.path("M 10 50");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
pathCommand += "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20 " + "c -10   0   0  20  15  20 ";
pc.animate({path: pathCommand, stroke: '#000','stroke-width': 3},2000);
}
```

this is not giving me what I exactly want.
Can anyone tell me how should I do it to show as this is drawing progrssively, with raphael js??
Thanks for any help

Comment: This link has some good information on the problem.  It may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js

Comment: I have tried that but it isn't working with my case

Comment: anyways I have got its solutions from my so many tries :) one worked

Comment: Glad you got a solution.  I'd suggest posting your solution as an answer to this question and mark it accepted.  That will help complete this question, and potentially help other people with a similar problem.

Comment: I think CM Kanode's right -- I'd like to see your solution as well.  I tackled this same problem like this (http://jsfiddle.net/zPRha/31/), but there are a dozen ways to skin this kitty.

Comment: Zero's answer is genius. I'll have to remember that.

Comment: I saw this solution for straight lines so I tried it for my coil animation also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = [ { stroke: "M 150 150", time: 0},
            { stroke: "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20", time: 800},
            { stroke: "c -10   0   0  20  15  20", time: 600},
            { stroke: "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20", time: 800},
            { stroke: "c -10   0   0  20  15  20", time: 600},
            { stroke: "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20", time: 800},
            { stroke: "c -10   0   0  20  15  20", time: 600},
            { stroke: "c  15   0  25 -20  15 -20", time: 800},
            { stroke: "c -10   0   0  20  15  20", time: 600} ];
var drawnPath = s[0].stroke;
var myPath = paper.path(drawnPath).attr({"stroke-width": 3,"stroke": "#000"});
var temp = 1;
animateMyPath();
function animateMyPath() {
if (temp < s.length) {
    drawnPath += s[temp].stroke;
    myPath.animate({path: drawnPath}, s[temp].time, animateMyPath);
    temp++;
    }
}
```

Please tell me is this correct way to do this, as I am new to this javascript programming.

Comment: Aren't you missing a space in `drawnPath += s[temp].stroke;`?

Comment: @Shruti  Looks good.  If I get a chance, I'll look into other solutions.  I'm curious now, but work demands my time.  :(

Comment: @CMKanode: ya sure, if u get time have please tell if anything in this needs to improve.