# How can I animate a vector path being drawn with Raphael JS?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

How can I animate a vector path being drawn with Raphael JS?

I have a set of coordinates that I would like to connect using Raphael JS.

On a grid, the coordinates are (x,y sets). I would like to start from one end and "connect the dots" as the user watches. The end product would look something like this:

[Picture 9.png http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/8013/picture9my.png](http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/8013/picture9my.png)

Ideally, I would like to be able to make the paths curved so they would look more like this (coordinates added for reference):

[Picture 10.png http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1789/picture10fc.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1789/picture10fc.png)

The coordinates are:

```
26,-6
14,-12
5,-20
11,-28
14,-37
5,-40
```

I've been searching Google and I have read through this question [How to draw a vector path progressively? (Raphael.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js/5073832#5073832) but I am trying to use Raphael.js specifically and the example on that page for Raphael.js does not seem to work nor does it talk about using multiple coordinate points for inputs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Progressive Paths**

Drawing a path progressively is easy to do.  I dislike the second-most-accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js/5073832#5073832) because it recreates a path at every step, clearing the paper in between.  Here's the utility function I've used time and time again:

```
function drawpath( canvas, pathstr, duration, attr, callback )
{
    var guide_path = canvas.path( pathstr ).attr( { stroke: "none", fill: "none" } );
    var path = canvas.path( guide_path.getSubpath( 0, 1 ) ).attr( attr );
    var total_length = guide_path.getTotalLength( guide_path );
    var last_point = guide_path.getPointAtLength( 0 );
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval_length = 50;
    var result = path;        

    var interval_id = setInterval( function()
    {
        var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var this_length = elapsed_time / duration * total_length;
        var subpathstr = guide_path.getSubpath( 0, this_length );            
        attr.path = subpathstr;

        path.animate( attr, interval_length );
        if ( elapsed_time >= duration )
        {
            clearInterval( interval_id );
            if ( callback != undefined ) callback();
                guide_path.remove();
        }                                       
    }, interval_length );  
    return result;
}
```

You can see it in action [on my site](http://voidblossom.com/tests/pathTransform.php).

This alone would make animating the progressive path construction of your points in a linear fashion absolutely simple.  You'd simply compile your path...

```
var sequence_path = ["M26,-6", "L14,-12", "L5,-20", "L11,-28", "L14,-37", "L5,-40"];
```

And then pass it to whatever path animation function you've set up.  In my case,

```
drawpath( paper, 
          sequence_path, 
          3500, 
          { stroke: 'black', 'stroke-width': 2, 'stroke-opacity': 1, fill: 'none', 'fill-opacity': 0 }, 
          function()
          {
              alert("All done");    // trigger whatever you want here
          } );
```

**Curve Interpolation**

Raphael 2.0's Catmull Rom feature makes curving gracefully between your points extremely straightforward (thanks to Erik Dahlström for pointing this out).  All you need to do is construct a path using the 'R' command to move between points, and Raphael will do the rest.

```
function generateInterpolatedPath( points )
{
    var path_sequence = [];
    path_sequence.push( "M", points[0].x, points[0].y );
    path_sequence.push( "R" );
    for ( var i = 1; i < points.length; i++ )
    {
        path_sequence.push( points[i].x, points[i].y );
    }
    return path_sequence;
}
```

You can see all the pieces working together [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/interpolation.php).

Comment: @KevinNielsen, I've been using this, but I've just noticed that it runs faster than expected in Firefox.  I've got a path of 4 points and if I set it to 2 seconds (or more), it takes less time than that.

Comment: @Jayen -- can you point me to your code?  I'd be happy to take a look at it this weekend.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Catmull Rom (see http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path) to get the smooth curve through the given points.

Live demo [here](http://raphaeljs.com/jsconfeu/#27) (click to assign points, then shift-click to transition to Catmull Rom curve).

Comment: Thanks, @Erik.  I hadn't seen the Catmull-Rom spline technique had been built into 2.0 -- that's pretty slick.  I hope you'll pardon me for incorporating it into my own answer.