# Raphaël animations using a frame timer

Tags: javascript, raphael, kineticjs

I am currently starting with Raphaël and I am having a hard time figuring out how to make animations in a flexible way using a frame with a timer.

With KineticJS, this was very easy. All I needed was to write something like:

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame){
  circle.setSomeAttribute(someFunction(frame.time));
}, layer);
anim.start();
```

This way I can actually put anything I want inside `someFunction()` and have better control over the values passed to the proprety over time. Is there anyway I can easily do this with Raphaël?

Thanks :)

Comment: Never used Raphael but had a quick look at the docs and it seems Raphael has more a css style animation where you define the animation and then start/stop it sorta thing.  Where you want more of a frames a second sorta thing.  Maybe you should just look at a more js way of doing things, this article might help you.... https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RaphaelJS will let you break animation steps down by percentages.  For example:

```
    gear.stop().animate({
        "0%": { transform: gear.__start },
        "20%": { transform: gear.__start + ' r' + gear.__dir + '180'},
        "40%": { transform: gear.__start + ' r0'},
        "80%": { transform: gear.__start + ' r' + gear.__dir + '180'},
        "100%": { transform: gear.__start + ' r0'},
    }, 3000 );
```

This will bypass easing, AFAIK. Anyhow, see http://jsfiddle.net/Cy8DQ/ for a working example.

Comment: This is very interesting to know. Unfortunately it doesn't help in this very particular situation because I wasn't satisfied with the transformation generated with `animate()` (it sort of picks the shortest way to the aim).
What I wanted to do actually is change the length of a subpath over time from 0% to 100% of original length. So it would have been very easy to just change the subpath following a timer.

Comment: @TKrugg: Easing will only give you control over timing, but to affect path, you can do it this way.  Instead of "20%": { transform: ... }, you can do "20%": { path: "..." } -- this will animate paths from step 1 to 2.

Comment: @pp19dd -- another +1 from me.  That fiddle is brilliant.

Comment: Finally I figured out how to do it. I had to change the whole approach and think the animations the Raphael way. Your example really helped. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you're asking, but you may just want to define your own easing formula.

```
Raphael.easing_formulas.myEasingFormula = function(n) { 
        //n is fraction of time elapsed
        return myOperationOn(n);    
    };
```

If none of the baked-in easing methods satisfy your needs, it's easy to make your own. You can see the formulas for the standard easings in Raphael [here in the source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.js#L2763). You're just returning a new fractional value to apply to the transformations on the elements of your choice.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, I wasn't satisfied with what `animate()` was doing so unfortunately changing the easing wouldn't help. That aside, this feature looks very interesting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe everybody who's spent any time with Raphael has had the opportunity to find its path animations woefully inadequate.  I've seen a few good stabs at addressing this here on SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js) is the most comprehensive).  Bottom line, there's no great solution out of the box.

I typically use this utility function (easily converted to a Raphael plugin, if you find such packaging more convenient):

```
function drawpath( canvas, pathstr, duration, attr, callback )
{
    var guide_path = canvas.path( pathstr ).attr( { stroke: "none", fill: "none" } );
    var path = canvas.path( guide_path.getSubpath( 0, 1 ) ).attr( attr );
    var total_length = guide_path.getTotalLength( guide_path );
    var last_point = guide_path.getPointAtLength( 0 );
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval_length = 50;
    var result = path;        

    var interval_id = setInterval( function()
    {
        var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var this_length = elapsed_time / duration * total_length;
        var subpathstr = guide_path.getSubpath( 0, this_length );            
        attr.path = subpathstr;

        path.animate( attr, interval_length );
        if ( elapsed_time >= duration )
        {
            clearInterval( interval_id );
            if ( callback != undefined ) callback();
            guide_path.remove();
        }                                       
    }, interval_length );  
    return result;
}
```

You can use this to gradually "draw in" a line of almost unlimited complexity.  Firefox still isn't fast enough to calc its way through complex paths in real time, but Chrome's great, and it's still VML friendly.

See a few of my applications [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/cursive.php) and [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/pathTransform.php).