# raphael draw continuous line

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am trying to draw continuous lines on raphael canvas. Say, line 1 starts from source A and ends at B, line 2 starts at B and this continues till the user triggers an event(stop drawing).

How do i achieve this.?

Thanks in advance.
Priyanka

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. please read the SO [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). your question does not show what you have already tried, what google results have you found, etc.

Comment: [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea8bj/) is from an answer to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073862/123033).