# Creating a drawing effect

Tags: html, css, svg

I am a photographer and programmer who travels around the coast taking photos. I was trying to display they location of where I took the photo based of the meta data of the picture on the database. I want to draw an animated map like that one on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2D6D.jpg) . What would be the most efficient way of drawing the map dynamic map? Below I used an image; however, I wanted to create a pencil drawing feel, maybe with svg (this may be hard?) ?

```css
.body-cnt{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/HqIN8NV.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class='body-cnt'></div>
```

Comment: Draw it in Illustrator and export as SVG? Sounds pretty straightforward to me...

Comment: Google, _"SVG line animation"_ - [vivus.js](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/).

Comment: Thank you! Did not think of it that way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631019/how-to-draw-a-vector-path-progressively-raphael-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so after a hour or two here is what I came up with.

```css
.svg-cnt{
 position: absolute;
 
 left:0;
 top: 0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.path{
 stroke-dasharray: 2200;
   stroke-dashoffset: 25;
   animation: dash 3s linear;
}
svg{
 position: absolute;
 
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;

 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 
}

@keyframes dash {
  from
 {
  stroke-dashoffset: 2200;
 }
  to 
 {
      stroke-dashoffset: 25;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-cnt">
<?xml version="1.0"?><svg class='svg-item' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width='60%' height='85%'  viewBox="0 0 650 607" preserveAspectRatio="none">
 <g display="inline">
<path class="path" fill="#f5f5f5" stroke="#5f5f5f" stroke-width="3" d="m73,85.883003c0,0 1.075996,0.382996 2,0c1.306999,-0.541 0.693001,-2.185806 2,-3.999802c0.827003,-1.147301 0.810997,-3.018105 1,-4c1.017998,-5.288002 1.693001,-6.186005 3,-8c0.827003,-1.147301 1,-2 1,-3c0,-1 0.823997,-1.0979 2,-3c0.526001,-0.8507 0.075996,-1.617401 1,-2c1.306999,-0.541203 1,-2 2,-2c1,0 1.693001,-0.458801 3,-1c0.924004,-0.382702 2,-1 3,-1c1,0 1,1 1,2c0,1 1,2 1,4c0,1 -0.526001,2.1493 0,3c1.175987,1.9021 2.292999,1.2929 3,2c0.707001,0.7071 1.292999,1.2929 2,2c0.707001,0.7071 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 3,1 4,1c1,0 1.692993,0.458801 3,1c0.924004,0.382599 3,0 4,0c1,0 2.075996,-0.382698 3,0c1.307007,0.541199 2,1 3,1c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2.026993,0.770195 3,1c2.175995,0.513695 3,1 4,1c1,0 2.585999,-1.414299 4,0c0.707001,0.7071 2,1 3,1c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 3,1 4,1c1,0 4.026993,0.770195 4,1c-0.026993,0.229698 2,1 4,0c2,-1 3.151993,-0.765404 5,0c1.307007,0.541199 2,1 3,1c1,0 2.692993,0.458801 4,1c0.923996,0.382599 2.076004,-0.382698 3,0c1.307007,0.541199 3,1 4,1c1,0 2,0 3,0c2,0 4,1 5,1c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 2.585999,-1.414299 4,0c0.707001,0.7071 2.039001,0.519402 5,1c3.121002,0.506798 4,0.999802 6,0.999802c2,0 3,1 4,1c2,0 5,0 6,0c1,0 1.692993,0.459 3,1c1.847992,0.765999 3.027008,-0.230003 4,0c2.175995,0.514 3,1 4,1c1,0 2,0 6,0c1,0 2,1 4,1c2,0 5,0 6,0c1,0 1.824005,0.486 4,1c0.972992,0.229996 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,1 4,1c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 1.692993,0.459 3,1c0.924011,0.382996 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c2,0 2,1 5,1c1,0 3,1 5,1c1,0 2,0 4,0c1,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 1,1 2,1c1,0 2.692993,0.459 4,1c0.924011,0.382996 2,0 3,0c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,1 4,1c1,0 1.692993,0.459 3,1c0.924011,0.382996 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 1,0c-1,0 -2.585999,1.413994 -4,0c-0.707001,-0.707001 0,-2 1,-3c1,-1 1.692993,-1.459 3,-2c1.847992,-0.765007 2.075989,-0.617004 3,-1c1.307007,-0.541 2.292999,-1.707001 3,-1c0.707001,0.706993 1.292999,2.292999 2,3c0.707001,0.706993 1.617004,0.075996 2,1c0.540985,1.306999 1.540009,2.053993 2,4c0.514008,2.175995 1.292999,2.292999 2,3c0.707001,0.706993 1.692993,1.459 3,2c0.924011,0.382996 2,1 3,1c1,0 1.292999,0.292999 2,1c0.707001,0.706993 1.292999,1.292999 2,2c0.707001,0.706993 2.292999,0.292999 3,1c0.707001,0.706993 1.075989,0.616997 2,1c1.307007,0.541 2,1 3,1c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 2.292999,-0.293007 3,-1c0.707001,-0.707001 2.292999,0.706993 3,0c0.707001,-0.707001 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 2.292999,0.706993 3,0c0.707001,-0.707001 0.692993,-1.459 2,-2c0.924011,-0.383003 2,-1 3,-1c1,0 1.692993,-0.459 3,-1c0.924011,-0.383003 3,-1 4,-1c2,0 3,0 4,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c2,0 3,0 5,0c1,0 2.075989,-0.383003 3,0c1.307007,0.541 2,1 3,2c1,1 2.075989,1.616997 3,2c1.307007,0.541 1.292999,1.292999 2,2c0.707001,0.706993 1.148987,0.473999 2,1c1.902008,1.17601 2.459015,2.694 3,4c0.382996,0.924004 1,1 2,2c1,1 2.075989,1.616997 3,2c1.307007,0.541 3,2 4,3c1,1 1.292999,1.292984 2,2c0.707001,0.706993 2.027008,0.769997 3,1c2.175995,0.514 2.692993,1.459 4,2c0.924011,0.383003 2.027008,0.769997 3,1c2.175995,0.514 3.292999,1.292992 4,1.999992c0.707001,0.707001 1.075989,0.617004 2,1c1.307007,0.541 2,1 2,2c0,1 1,3 1,4c0,2 0.459015,2.694 1,4c0.382996,0.924011 0.459015,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.924011 -0.707001,2.292999 0,3c0.707001,0.707001 0.292999,1.292999 1,2c0.707001,0.707001 1.292999,0.292999 2,1c0.707001,0.707001 0.292999,1.292999 1,2c0.707001,0.707001 0.292999,1.292999 1,2c0.707001,0.707001 1,2 1,3c0,1 1,2 1,3c0,1 0.459015,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.924011 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,4c0,1 0,3 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,2 1.414001,3.585999 0,5c-0.707001,0.707001 -1.292999,1.292999 -2,2c-0.707001,0.707001 -0.292999,1.292999 -1,2c-0.707001,0.707001 -1,1 -1,2c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 1,1 2,1c2,0 3,0 5,0c1,0 1.692993,-0.459 3,-1c0.924011,-0.382996 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 2.459015,0.307007 3,-1c0.382996,-0.923996 1,-1 2,-2c1,-1 1.075989,-1.616989 2,-2c1.307007,-0.541 0.585999,-1.585999 2,-3c0.707001,-0.707001 2,-1 3,-2c1,-1 1.292999,-1.292999 2,-2c0.707001,-0.707001 1.692993,-1.459 3,-2c0.924011,-0.382996 2.292999,-0.292999 3,-1c0.707001,-0.707001 0.292999,-1.292999 1,-2c0.70697,-0.707001 1.29303,-0.292999 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707001 1,-2 1,-3c0,-1 1,-1 1,-2c0,-1 1.414001,-2.585999 0,-4c-0.70697,-0.707001 -1.29303,-0.292999 -2,-1c-1.414001,-1.414001 -0.382996,-3.075989 0,-4c0.541016,-1.306 1,-2 2,-2c1,0 1.29303,-0.292999 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707001 2,0 3,0c1,0 2,0 3,0c1,0 1.692993,-0.459 3,-1c0.924011,-0.382996 1.29303,-0.292999 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707001 2,0 3,-1c1,-1 1.692993,-1.459 3,-2c0.924011,-0.382996 1.29303,-0.292999 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707001 0.617004,-1.075989 1,-2c0.541016,-1.306 1,-2 1,-3c0,-2 0.458984,-3.692993 1,-5c0.382996,-0.923996 0.617004,-1.075989 1,-2c0.541016,-1.306 1.29303,-1.292999 2,-2c0.70697,-0.707001 1.29303,-0.292999 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707001 1.692993,-1.459 3,-2c0.924011,-0.382996 2.29303,-1.292999 3,-2c0.70697,-0.707001 1.29303,-1.292999 2,-2c0.70697,-0.707001 1,-1 3,-1c1,0 2,-1 3,-1c1,0 2.075989,-0.616989 3,-0.999992c1.307007,-0.541 2,-1 3,-1c1,0 1,-1 3,-1c1,0 2.29303,0.706993 3,0c0.70697,-0.707016 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 1.29303,-0.293007 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707016 1,-1 2,-1c1,0 1.29303,-0.293007 2,-1c0.70697,-0.707016 0.617004,-2.075996 1,-3c0.541016,-1.306 1.29303,-1.293007 2,-2c0.70697,-0.707016 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 0,-3 0,-4c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-2 0,-3 0,-4c0,-1 -0.765015,-2.152 0,-4c0.541016,-1.306 1.29303,-2.293007 2,-3c0.70697,-0.707001 1,-3 1,-4c0,-1 1,-1 1,-2c0,-1 1,-3 1,-4c0,-1.999802 1.692993,-2.458603 3,-2.999802c0.924011,-0.382698 2.026978,-0.770302 3,-1c2.176025,-0.513802 3.151978,-1.765404 5,-1c1.307007,0.541199 2.458984,1.693398 3,3c0.382996,0.923897 1,1.999802 2,3.999802c1,2 2,2 2,3c0,1 1,2 1,3c0,1 0.486023,2.823997 1,5c0.22998,0.973 0.458984,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.923996 0.458984,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.923996 1.29303,1.292999 2,2c0.70697,0.706993 0.617004,1.075996 1,2c0.541016,1.306999 0.29303,2.292999 1,3c0.70697,0.706993 1.29303,0.292999 2,1c0.70697,0.706993 -0.382996,2.075996 0,3c0.541016,1.306999 1,2 1,3c0,1 0,3 0,4c0,2 -0.29303,2.292984 -1,3c-0.70697,0.706993 -0.585999,0.585983 -2,2c-0.70697,0.706993 -1,1 -3,1c-1,0 -0.585999,0.585991 -2,1.999992c-0.70697,0.707001 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2.458984,0.307007 -3,-1c-0.382996,-0.923996 -1,-0.999992 -1,1c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -1,1 -2,2c-1,1 -2.075989,1.617004 -3,2c-1.307007,0.541 -2.458984,0.694 -3,2c-0.382996,0.924011 0,3 0,5c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,4c0,1 0.382996,2.076004 0,3c-0.541016,1.307007 -0.541016,2.694 0,4c0.382996,0.924011 0.382996,2.076004 0,3c-0.541016,1.307007 -0.541016,1.694 0,3c0.382996,0.924011 2,1 3,2c1,1 1.098022,1.824997 3,3c0.851013,0.526001 1,1 1,0c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 -0.179016,0.299011 3,2c0.882019,0.472 1,1 2,2c1,1 1.458984,1.694 2,3c0.382996,0.924011 0,2 0,3c0,1 -1,1 -2,1c-1,0 -2.692993,0.459 -4,1c-0.924011,0.383011 -2.29303,0.707001 -3,0c-1.414001,-1.414001 -0.692993,-2.459 -2,-3c-0.924011,-0.382996 -1,-1 -2,-1c-2,0 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-0.70697,0.707001 -1.29303,1.292999 -2,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -1.692993,0.459 -3,1c-0.924011,0.383011 -3.29303,0.292999 -4,1c-0.70697,0.707001 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-0.70697,0.707001 -1,3 -2,3c-1,0 -1.29303,1.292999 -2,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -1.458984,0.694 -2,2c-0.382996,0.924011 -0.924011,2.383011 0,2c1.307007,-0.541 2.148987,-0.473999 3,-1c1.901978,-1.175003 2,-2 3,-2c1,0 2.692993,-1.459 4,-2c1.848022,-0.764999 2,1 2,2c0,1 0.70697,2.292999 0,3c-1.414001,1.414001 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-1.414001,1.414001 -1,2 -2,2c-1,0 -2.075989,-0.382996 -3,0c-1.307007,0.541 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-0.70697,0.707001 -1,1 -2,1c-1,0 -1.692993,0.459 -3,1c-0.924011,0.383011 -2.29303,-0.707001 -3,0c-0.70697,0.707001 -0.382996,2.076004 0,3c0.541016,1.307007 1.458984,1.694 2,3c0.382996,0.924011 0.458984,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.924011 0,3 0,5c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -2,1 -2,2c0,2 -0.075989,3.617004 -1,4c-1.307007,0.541 -0.098022,2.824997 -2,4c-0.851013,0.526001 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1,-2 -2,-2c-1,0 -0.617004,-1.075989 -1,-2c-0.541016,-1.306 -1.458984,-1.692993 -2,-3c-0.382996,-0.923996 -1,-3 -1,-2c0,1 1.458984,0.694 2,2c0.382996,0.924011 0.458984,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.924011 1.486023,1.824005 2,4c0.22998,0.973007 1,1 1,2c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,2 1,2 1,3c0,2 0,3 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -0.692993,1.459015 -2,2c-0.924011,0.382996 -1.29303,-1.292999 -2,-2c-0.70697,-0.707001 -1.29303,-2.292999 -2,-3c-1.414001,-1.414001 -0.617004,-3.075989 -1,-4c-0.541016,-1.306 -1.29303,-2.292999 -2,-3c-1.414001,-1.414001 -0.458984,-2.692993 -1,-4c-0.382996,-0.923996 -0.458984,-1.692993 -1,-3c-0.765015,-1.847992 0,-1 0,0c0,2 0.22998,3.027008 0,4c-0.513977,2.17601 -1.29303,2.292999 -2,3c-0.70697,0.707001 -0.585999,0.585999 -2,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -2,1 -2,2c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 1.29303,1.292999 2,2c0.70697,0.707001 0.692993,1.459015 2,2c0.924011,0.382996 1,1 2,1c1,0 2,1 3,2c1,1 1,2 1,3c0,1 -0.70697,3.292999 0,4c0.70697,0.707001 2.075989,-0.382996 3,0c1.307007,0.541016 2.458984,1.694 3,3c0.765015,1.847992 1.458984,2.694 2,4c0.382996,0.924011 0,2 0,4c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 -1.29303,1.292999 -2,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -0.692993,2.459015 -2,3c-0.924011,0.382996 -1.382996,2.076019 -1,3c1.08197,2.613007 1.617004,3.076019 2,4c0.541016,1.307007 1.382996,2.076019 1,3c-0.541016,1.307007 -1.528015,1.118011 -2,2c-1.700989,3.179016 -2.387024,3.917999 -5,5c-0.924011,0.382996 -1.075989,0.617004 -2,1c-1.307007,0.541016 -2,1 -3,2c-1,1 -1.692993,1.459015 -3,2c-0.924011,0.382996 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-1.414001,1.414001 -0.617004,3.076019 -1,4c-0.541016,1.307007 -1.29303,1.292999 -2,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -0.29303,1.292999 -1,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -2.77002,0.027008 -3,1c-0.513977,2.175995 -1,3 -2,3c-1,0 -0.29303,1.292999 -1,2c-0.70697,0.707001 -0.617004,1.076019 -1,2c-0.541016,1.307007 -1.29303,1.292999 -2,2c-1.414001,1.414001 -1,3 -1,4c0,1 -0.29303,2.292999 -1,3c-0.70697,0.707001 -1.458984,2.694 -2,4c-0.382996,0.924011 0.307007,2.186005 -1,4c-0.827026,1.147003 -1.486023,1.824005 -2,4c-0.458984,1.946991 -1,3 -1,4c0,1 0.70697,2.292999 0,3c-0.70697,0.707001 0.414001,2.585999 -1,4c-0.70697,0.707001 -1.458984,0.694 -2,2c-0.382996,0.924011 -1,2 -1,3c0,1 -1,2 -1,3c0,2 0,3 0,4c0,1 0.458984,1.694 1,3c0.382996,0.924011 0.617004,2.076019 1,3c0.541016,1.307007 1.458984,1.694 2,3c0.382996,0.924011 1,2 1,3c0,1 1,1 1,2c0,1 1,2 1,3c0,1 0.617004,1.076019 1,2c0.541016,1.307007 1.172974,1.852997 2,3c1.307007,1.813995 0.541016,3.054016 1,5c0.513977,2.175995 1.77002,3.027008 2,4c0.513977,2.175995 1.234985,3.152008 2,5c0.541016,1.307007 1.172974,1.852997 2,3c1.307007,1.813995 0.617004,3.076019 1,4c0.541016,1.307007 2,3 2,5c0,1 1,2 1,3c0,1 1.458984,3.694 2,5c0.765015,1.847992 1,2 1,3c0,2 0.29303,3.292999 1,4c0.70697,0.707001 0,3 0,4c0,1 0,3 0,4c0,1 0.382996,2.076019 0,3c-0.541016,1.307007 -2.29303,0.292999 -3,1c-0.70697,0.707001 -1,1 -2,1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1,-1 -2,-2c-1,-1 -0.692993,-2.458984 -2,-3c-0.924011,-0.382996 -0.29303,-1.292999 -1,-2c-0.70697,-0.707001 -1.075989,-0.617004 -2,-1c-1.307007,-0.540985 -2.075989,-1.617004 -3,-2c-1.307007,-0.540985 -2.458984,-1.692993 -3,-3c-0.382996,-0.923981 -1.617004,-1.075989 -2,-2c-0.541016,-1.306 -1.823975,-1.097992 -3,-3c-0.526001,-0.850006 -0.148987,-1.473999 -1,-2c-1.901978,-1.174988 -1.617004,-2.075989 -2,-3c-0.540985,-1.306 -1.824005,-1.097992 -3,-3c-0.526001,-0.850006 -0.459015,-1.692993 -1,-3c-0.382996,-0.923981 -1,-1 -1,-2c0,-1 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-1 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-2 0,-3 0,-5c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 0.707001,-2.292999 0,-3c-0.707001,-0.707001 -0.769989,-1.027008 -1,-2c-0.514008,-2.175995 -2,-2 -2,-3c0,-1 -0.292999,-1.292999 -1,-2c-1.414001,-1.414001 -3,0 -5,0c-1,0 -1.692993,-0.458984 -3,-1c-0.924011,-0.382996 -2.824005,0.902008 -4,-1c-0.526001,-0.850006 -2.292999,-0.292999 -3,-1c-0.707001,-0.707001 -0.692993,-1.458984 -2,-2c-0.924011,-0.382996 -2,0 -4,0c-2,0 -3,1 -4,1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2.292999,0.707001 -3,0c-0.707001,-0.707001 -1.692993,-1.458984 -3,-2c-1.847992,-0.764984 -3.013,-0.839996 -4,-1c-3.121002,-0.505981 -4,-2 -5,-2c-2,0 -4,0 -5,0c-2,0 -4,0 -6,0c-1,0 -3,0 -4,0c-2,0 -3.075989,-0.382996 -4,0c-1.307007,0.541016 -2,1 -4,1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -3.075989,-0.382996 -4,0c-1.307007,0.541016 -2,1 -3,1c-1,0 -1.186005,0.692993 -3,2c-1.147003,0.826996 -3,2 -3,3c0,1 1.292999,0.292999 2,1c0.707001,0.707001 0.292999,1.292999 1,2c0.707001,0.707001 1.692993,0.459015 3,1c0.924011,0.382996 2.292999,1.292999 3,2c0.707001,0.707001 0.292999,3.292999 1,4c0.707001,0.707001 1,1 1,2c0,1 0,2 -1,3c-1,1 -3,1 -4,1c-2,0 -3.292999,-0.292999 -4,-1c-0.707001,-0.707001 -0.617004,-1.075989 -1,-2c-0.540985,-1.306 -2,-1 -3,-2c-1,-1 -1.692993,-0.540985 -3,0c-0.924011,0.382996 -1.692993,0.459015 -3,1c-0.924011,0.382996 -1.824005,1.485992 -4,2c-0.972992,0.230011 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1.692993,-2.186005 -3,-4c-0.826996,-1.147003 -2.292999,-0.292999 -3,-1c-0.707001,-0.707001 -1,-1 -2,-1c-1,0 -2.075989,0.382996 -3,0c-1.307007,-0.540985 -3,-1 -4,-1c-3,0 -3.692993,0.459015 -5,1c-0.924011,0.382996 -2,1 -4,1c-2,0 -3,0 -4,0c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1.075989,0.617004 -2,1c-1.307007,0.541016 -2.292999,1.292999 -3,2c-1.414001,1.414001 -1,2 -2,2c-1,0 -2,1 -3,1c-1,0 -2.075989,0.617004 -3,1c-1.307007,0.541016 -1.292999,1.292999 -2,2c-0.707001,0.707001 -1.173004,0.852997 -2,2c-1.307007,1.813995 -1.148987,2.473999 -2,3c-1.902008,1.175995 -1.692993,2.459015 -3,3c-0.924011,0.382996 -3.075989,0.617004 -4,1c-1.307007,0.541016 -2,1 -3,1c-1,0 -1.692993,0.459015 -3,1c-1.847992,0.765991 -2.292999,0.292999 -3,1c-1.414001,1.414001 -0.617004,2.076019 -1,3c-0.540985,1.307007 -1,2 -1,3c0,1 1.414001,2.585999 0,4c-0.707001,0.707001 -1.485992,0.824005 -2,3c-0.230011,0.972992 0.707001,3.292999 0,4c-0.707001,0.707001 -1,3 -1,5c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,2 0,3c0,1 0,3 0,4c0,2 0,3 -2,3c-1,0 -3.148987,0.526001 -4,0c-1.902008,-1.174988 -3.027008,-1.769989 -4,-2c-2.175995,-0.514008 -4.585999,0.414001 -6,-1c-0.707001,-0.707001 -2.075989,-1.617004 -3,-2c-2.613007,-1.082001 -3.459015,-1.692993 -4,-3c-0.382996,-0.923981 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 0,-2 0,-3c0,-2 -1,-5 -1,-6c0,-1 -2.485992,-4.824005 -3,-7c-0.230011,-0.972992 -1,-2 -2,-4c-1,-2 -2,-3 -3,-4c-1,-1 -1,-3 -2,-4c-1,-1 -1.459015,-1.692993 -2,-3c-0.765015,-1.847992 -1.459015,-1.692993 -2,-3c-0.382996,-0.923981 -0.292999,-3.292999 -1,-4c-0.707001,-0.707001 -0.473999,-1.148987 -1,-2c-1.175995,-1.902008 -1.617004,-2.075989 -2,-3c-0.540985,-1.306 -1.292999,-2.292999 -2,-3c-0.707001,-0.707001 -2.299011,1.052002 -4,0c-1.902008,-1.174988 -2.075989,-1.617004 -3,-2c-1.307007,-0.540985 -2,-1 -3,-1c-1,0 -2.075989,-0.382996 -3,0c-1.307007,0.541016 -2,2 -3,3c-2,2 -2.473999,3.149994 -3,4c-1.175995,1.902008 -3.292999,1.292999 -4,2c-0.707001,0.707001 -1,2 -2,2c-1,0 -1.386993,-0.916992 -4,-2c-0.924011,-0.382996 -1.473999,-1.148987 -2,-2c-1.175995,-1.902008 -2.076004,-1.617004 -3,-2c-1.307007,-0.540985 -2.292999,-1.292999 -3,-2c-0.707001,-0.707001 -1.485992,-0.824005 -2,-3c-0.229996,-0.972992 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-1 -1,-3 -1,-4c0,-2 -1,-3 -1,-4c0,-1 -0.917999,-1.386993 -2,-4c-0.764999,-1.847992 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-1 -1.459,-0.692993 -2,-2c-0.382996,-0.923981 -1.459,-1.692993 -2,-3c-0.382996,-0.923981 -0.692993,-1.186005 -2,-3c-0.826996,-1.147003 -2.292999,-1.292999 -3,-2c-1.414001,-1.414001 -0.692993,-2.458984 -2,-3c-0.923996,-0.382996 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1.585999,0.414001 -3,-1c-0.707001,-0.707001 -1,-1 -2,-1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2.076004,0.382996 -3,0c-1.307007,-0.540985 -2,-1 -3,-1c-1,0 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2.292999,-0.707001 -3,0c-0.707001,0.707001 -1,2 -1,3c0,1 -1,2 -2,2c-1,0 -2,0 -4,0c-2,0 -2.824005,-0.485992 -5,-1c-0.973007,-0.22998 -2,0 -4,0c-2,0 -5,-1 -6,-1c-1,0 -2.080002,-0.311005 -5,-1c-2.175995,-0.514008 -3,-1 -4,-1c-3,0 -5,-2 -6,-2c-1,0 -1.692993,-0.458984 -3,-1c-0.923996,-0.382996 -3,-1 -4,-2c-1,-1 -2.934013,-2.143982 -5,-3c-2.921997,-1.209991 -5.309998,-2.337006 -8,-4c-1.203003,-0.742981 -2.080002,-2.376007 -6,-4c-1.848007,-0.764984 -2.692993,-0.458984 -4,-1c-0.924004,-0.382996 -2.075996,-0.617004 -3,-1c-1.307007,-0.540985 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-1 0,-2 0,-6c0,-2 0,-3 -1,-3c-2,0 -2.692993,-0.458984 -4,-1c-0.924004,-0.382996 -2,0 -3,0c-3,0 -4,0 -6,0c-1,0 -3,-1 -5,-1c-2,0 -3.149002,0.526001 -4,0c-1.902,-1.174988 -2,-3 -4,-5c-1,-1 -1.616997,-1.075989 -2,-2c-0.541,-1.306 -0.292999,-2.292999 -1,-3c-0.707001,-0.707001 -0.769997,-1.027008 -1,-2c-0.514,-2.175995 -1.459,-2.692993 -2,-4c-0.383003,-0.923981 -0.172997,-1.852997 -1,-3c-1.306999,-1.813995 -0.693001,-3.458984 -2,-4c-0.923901,-0.382996 -2,-2 -2,-3c0,-1 -0.2929,-1.292999 -1,-2c-0.7071,-0.707001 -1,-1 -2,-3c-1,-2 -1.693501,-2.458984 -3,-3c-0.923901,-0.382996 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -1.0979,-0.824005 -3,-2c-0.850601,-0.526001 -2,0 -3,0c-1,0 -2,-1 -2,-2c0,-2 0,-3 0,-4c0,-2 -1,-3 -1,-5c0,-1 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-2 -0.458801,-3.692993 -1,-5c-0.382698,-0.923981 -0.917599,-3.386993 -2,-6c-0.382698,-0.923981 -1.486301,-2.824005 -2,-5c-0.229801,-0.972992 -0.617298,-2.075989 -1,-3c-0.541199,-1.306 -1,-2 -1,-3c0,-2 1.486301,-1.82399 2,-4c0.229801,-0.972992 0,-2 0,-3c0,-1 0,-2 0,-4c0,-2 -0.382698,-3.075989 0,-4c0.541199,-1.306 1,-2 1,-3c0,-1 0.7654,-3.151993 0,-5c-0.541199,-1.306 -1.103401,-3.905991 -2,-5c-2.2859,-2.787994 -1.6926,-4.185989 -3,-6c-0.8269,-1.147003 -3,-3 -4,-5c-1,-2 -1,-3 -1,-5c0,-1 0.2929,-1.292999 1,-2c1.4142,-1.414001 0.2929,-3.292999 1,-4c0.7071,-0.707001 0,-2 0,-5c0,-1 0,-3 0,-4c0,-2 -0.3074,-3.185989 1,-5c1.653801,-2.293991 5,-5 6,-6c1,-1 1.486301,-2.82399 2,-5c0.459499,-1.945999 -0.459499,-4.052994 0,-6c0.513699,-2.175995 0.540501,-4.052994 1,-6c0.513699,-2.175995 0.770199,-3.026993 1,-4c0.513699,-2.175995 1,-3 1,-4c0,-2 0.4935,-3.877991 1,-7c0.160198,-0.987 0.770199,-4.026993 1,-5c0.513699,-2.175995 1,-4 2,-5.999992c1,-2 1.458801,-2.693001 2,-4c0.382702,-0.924004 1.2929,-2.293007 2,-3c0.7071,-0.707016 0.2929,-2.293007 1,-3c0.7071,-0.707016 0.2346,-1.152 1,-3c0.541199,-1.306 0.235001,-3.152 2,-4c1.764999,-0.848 2.458801,-2.693001 3,-4c0.7654,-1.848 0.617302,-3.076004 1,-4c0.541199,-1.306 1.770199,-2.027 2,-3c0.513699,-2.176003 2,-3 2,-6c0,-2 0,-3 0,-4c0,-1 -0.7654,-2.152 0,-4c0.541199,-1.306 1,-2.999802 1,-3.999802c0,-2 0,-3 0,-4c0,-2 0,-3 0,-5c0,-2 0,-3 0,-4c0,-1 -0.7071,-2.2929 0,-3c0.707001,-0.7071 7.235001,3.735802 14,10c2.074997,1.9217 3.075996,1.617302 4,2c1.306999,0.541199 2,1 3,1l1,0l1,0l-1,0"/>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
```